# How to do raw mongodb operations in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm asking this because when I write unit tests, I want to drop the test database and insert some initialize data, and also check the data in mongodb in testing. So I need raw operations to mongodb.

How to do this in mongoose? What I can do now is just create the connection, and not find any document in mongoose's official site.

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 mongoose.connect('mongo://localhost/shuzu_test');

 // get the connection
 var conn = mongoose.connection;
```

But how to:

1. drop the database
2. create a collection
3. write some data to a collection
4. query a collection
5. drop a collection

Answer (score 53, accepted):

See the section on "Driver Access" in the docs:
http://mongoosejs.com/

Basically you can get access to the [node-mongodb-native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) driver by doing `YourModel.collection` and then you can `insert` or `remove` or `drop` or whatever you need.

There's not a doc, but with this approach you'll get access to everything in here:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#collection-js

**Edit:**

In your case you may want to skip using mongoose in your test suite and use the  [node-mongodb-native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) directly, or even write a simple [mongodb shell script](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Scripting+the+shell) that can be run before your tests start.

Comment: About "using mognodb-native directly", I found if I defined indexes in mongoose schemas, they won't work well if I use mongodb-native to insert some data directly.

Comment: That's interesting. I thought the ensureIndex was run on startup? Hmm. Ahh yes, but this is in your test suite so it's not doing the Mongoose calls at all.

Comment: I have a complex MongoDB script that runs from the command line as follows:

    $ mongo mydb task.js

Since I can't run shell scripts in my server environment and need to schedule the above task, I figured I could run the Mongo script from a Node script. Is this possible through the native driver?

Comment: Does your environment allow you to setup cron jobs at all?

Comment: This answer refers to documentation which isn't very clear. Why not just write the code *and* link to the specific page in the documentation.

Comment: I don't see "Driver Access" on that page anymore.

Answer (score 85):

You can run mongodb commands using the native NodeJS driver by using `mongoose.connection.db`.  This accesses the NodeJS MongoDB driver, and **you don't need to create a mongoose model**.

#### An insert

```
mongoose.connection.db.collection('userCollection').insert({
  username: 'captain1',
  firstName: 'Steve',
  lastName: 'Rogers', 
});
```

#### An update

```
mongoose.connection.db.collection('userCollection').update(
  {someFilterProperty: true},
  {$set: {
     siteId: new mongoose.mongo.ObjectId('56cb91bdc5946f14678934ba'),
     hasNewSiteId: true}},
  {multi: true});
});
```

You can send every command specific to that database using the database connection db reference `mongoose.connection.db`.

This is the mongoose API doc:  http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-db

**Important**: Note some of the options in the NodeJS driver are different than the options in MongoDB shell commands.  For example `findOneAndUpdate()` uses `returnOriginal` instead of `returnNewDocument`.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44172870/404699) and [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate) for more on this.

Comment: I think this is the best general-access way to the native driver. For those searching in the original Mongoose API docs, here is the link for `Connection.prototype.db`: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-db

Comment: How do you print the result of the query?

Comment: I know this is old, but just for people that are still finding this, you can do this to get results: `Mongoose.connection.db.collection('collectionname').find({}).toArray((err,results) => { console.log(results); });`

Answer (score 6):

use this to run raw operations in mongoose.

```
  Model_name.collection.insertMany(array, { ordered: false },function(err, success){
            console.log(success);
        });
```

Comment: This answer requires a model to exist.  The question asks how to use "raw mongodb", which implies the user may not want the added requirement of a model.

Answer (score 4):

*Have encountered same trouble, to cleanup DBs after tests, and actual answer only confused because of absence "code blocks", so dig docs/code once more, for others-time-saving purpose posting this ;)*

Mongoose collection extends Mongodb collection

> /*
>      * section collection.js
>      * http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#collection-js
>      */
>
> interface CollectionBase extends mongodb.Collection {
>
> Documentation : http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html

Same goes for the connection:

> The Connection class exposed by require('mongoose')
>        is actually the driver's NativeConnection class.
>        connection.js defines a base class that the native
>         versions extend. See:
>         http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#drivers-node-mongodb-native-connection-js

So all "RAW" operations can be performed on collection/connection,
assuming that you have

```
 var connection = mongoose.connection;
```

then:

**1.drop the database:**

```
connection.dropDatabase()
```

**2.create a collection**

```
connection.collection('newcollection') // creates if not exists
```

**3.write some data to a collection**

```
connection.collection('mybenotnewcollection').bulkWrite([
  { insertOne: { whatewer: { you: 'need' } } },
]);
```

**4.query a collection**

that's obviously not a question: findAll, find, aggregate, all allowed (see the [Docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html))

**5.drop a collection**

```
connection.collection('notsonewcollection').drop()
```

Comment: Works all fine. But how can I check whether a collection exists? If I'm unsing connection.listCollections(), I'm getting an error: listCollections is not a function

Comment: @mcAngular2 check docs https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-collections

connection.collections

Answer (score 3):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(uri, options);
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.once('open', function () {
  db.collection('collection').find().toArray(function(err, result){
        console.log(result);
  });
}
```

Comment: a verbal explanation is often helpful

Answer (score 1):

The mongoose object has a mongo prototype which gives you access to native mongo driver

```
mongoose.mongo
```