# How to get updated document back from the findOneAndUpdate method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am using MongoDB with node js , i used `npm install mongodb`

I want to update an existing document and return the updated document , the document is updated correctly . but it returns the old document means the original document before update . i have used the `returnNewDocument:true` parameter but no use .

```
            var filter = {
                '_id': object_id
            },
            update = {
                $set: { "status" : data["status"] },
                $push: {
                    "statusHistory": {
                        $each: [{ status:data["status"],statusChangedTime:data["statusChangedTime"],comment:data["comment"]}],
                        $position:0,
                    }
                },
            }
            ,options = {
                //upsert: false,
                //multi: false,
                returnNewDocument: true
            };

            col.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, options,function(err, res) {
                if (err) {

                    console.log(err);
                }else {

                    console.log(res);
                }
            });
```

the response is

```
{ lastErrorObject: { updatedExisting: true, n: 1 },
  value: 
   { 
//original document
   },     
  ok: 1 }
```

when i directly go to mongoDB through terminal and try

```
db.MyCollection.find().pretty();
```

the document is updated correctly, it just returns the original instead of updated one.

Stuck here for 2 hours, any help is appreciated

in package.json

```
"mongodb": "^2.1.4",
```

Comment: What version of mongodb are using? 3.2?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

The Node.js [driver documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate) doesn't mention a `returnNewDocument` option for `findOneAndUpdate()` (which is an option for the [MongoDB shell command](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) with the same name).

Instead, it mentions an option called `returnOriginal`, which defaults to `true`. Try using that option, setting it to `false` to return the *updated* document instead of the original.

Comment: you are correct. It's unfortunate that naming inconsistencies cheeped into mongodb too. Hopefully, they'll fix it.

Comment: great  , that solved the problem  . thank you very much :) : )

Comment: lost 1 hour on this problem here. Thx a lot.

Comment: @Sulliwane you must be getting a different page then, because it clearly mentions `returnOriginal` ([image](http://imgur.com/x6LeXCy)).

Comment: wow, my bad !! we have the same page, different brains that's all ;)

Comment: Just my two cents, also when using `upsert:true` and specifying only `returnNewDocument: true` it returns `value: null` when the object is inserted the first time.

Comment: I had to use `new: true` in order to return the new document. `returnOriginal: false` and `returnNewDocument: true` did not work for me. Using Node v10.12.0 and mongoose 5.3.14.

Comment: Wow. What an inconsistency. Thank you!

Comment: It's now `{returnDocument: "after"}` for those on 4.1 [doc](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/interfaces/FindOneAndUpdateOptions.html#returnDocument)

Answer (score 20):

To get the updated document after performing the update operation we need to use the option `"returnDocument" : "after"` along with `"returnOriginal" : false`.

As per the latest mongodb node driver v3.6 documentation, **the usage of returnOriginal is deprecated**. But when I try only including `"returnDocument" : 'after'` without `"returnOriginal":false` its returning the original record instead of the updated record.
Using them both is giving the desired output of updated record instead of the original record.
(source : http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate)

The option
`"returnNewDocument" : true` is a mongo shell option and may not work in the node driver as per the official mongodb documentation ( mentioned here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/)

Comment: Worked like a charm (in 2021)! This answer needs to get more upvotes

Comment: Perfect. Time saver. :-)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It saved me time

Answer (score 13):

If you are seeing this latest 2018, neither returnNewDocument:true nor returnOriginal: false, works. You have to instead set a property called new to true as in {.., new: true} in the option object for your query.

Comment: This is only true for `findAndModify`, which is deprecated: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#findAndModify . Instead use `findOneAndUpdate` http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate with `returnOriginal`. The naming inconsistencies are insane.

Answer (score 8):

=== Aug 2021

With the release of v4 of the node.js client, it seems the old solution of `returnOriginal: false` (which was awful anyway) is no longer the correct answer.

To see the list of available options for the node.js findOneAndUpdate method: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.0/interfaces/findoneandupdateoptions.html

But in short, this should work:

```js
const doc = await <Collection>.findOneAndUpdate(
  { ... search },
  {
    $set: {
      field1: 'value 1',
      field2: ['value 2'],
      etc.
    },
  },
  {
    upsert: true,
    returnDocument: 'after', // this is new !
  }
)
```

Comment: This is correct in case you have updated `mongodb` driver in Aug 2021. Gave me a real headache for 60 good minutes. Thanks @Zach!

Answer (score 7):

The [NodeJS MongoDB driver](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate) has different arguments compared to the native MongoDB shell for the command `findOneAndUpdate()`. If you are using "mongodb": "^2.1.4" then use

> returnOriginal: false

instead

> returnNewDocument: true

.

Let's see below code:

```
db.collection('user_setting').findOneAndUpdate({user_id: data.user_id}, {$set: data}, {projection: dbConfig.userSetting, returnOriginal: false}, function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            callback({'error': 1, 'message': 'Internal server error! ' + err, 'data': null, 'status': 500});
        }   else {
                 console.log(res);
                /* { lastErrorObject: { updatedExisting: true, n: 1 },
                      value: 
                           { user_id: 1,
                             notification_alert: 1,
                             notification_sound: 1,
                             user_setting_id: 2 
                            },
                       ok: 1 
                  }      */       
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

If anyone else ran into this issue when using `{ returnOriginal: false }` within a Mongoose setup:

Mongoose uses `{ new: true }` instead of `{ returnOriginal: false }`.

The feature is referenced here: [Mongoose: findOneAndUpdate doesn't return updated document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811510/mongoose-findoneandupdate-doesnt-return-updated-document) and within the [Mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate):

> **Options:**
>
> **new:** *bool* - if true, return the modified document rather than the original. defaults to false (changed in 4.0)

So when using `findOneAndUpdate` add `new: true` to the method options:

```
...

const options = {
  new: true
};

col.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, options, function (err, res) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(res);
  }
});
```

Comment: Awesome! I use mongoose, and "new" was the only way to make it work. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

According to the actual source code and type definition for 4.0+, the *new* property is now `new`. Set it `true` to return the modified result.

```
interface QueryFindOneAndUpdateOptions extends QueryFindOneAndRemoveOptions {
  /** if true, return the modified document rather than the original. defaults to false (changed in 4.0) */
  new?: boolean;
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using 
mongoose: 5.8.9

with these lines below

```
const option = { new: true }
const account = await Account.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, option)
```

and this is working

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
req.db.collection(collectionName).findOneAndUpdate(
          { _id : commentById._id }, // matching parameters
           updateOpts, //updating parameters
          {returnOriginal: false}  //don't use **returnNewDocument**
         );
```