# How to create a new document 'if not exists' and return the new document with MongoDB NodeJS native driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, crud

I want to create a new document if it doesn't exist and return the new document once created, however if the document already exists I would like an exception to be thrown.

I think the way I am doing this seems hackish, is there a better means of doing this?

```
var query = { name: 'guaranteed to be unique' }
var new_doc = { ... }
var col = // the Mongo collection we're using

col.updateOne(
    query,
    new_doc,
    {upsert: true}
)
.then(update => col.findOne({_id, update.result.upserted.pop()._id}))
.then(doc => console.log(doc))
.catch( exception => console.log('that already exists') )
```

Comment: Depends if you want to update it if it does exist? If so you could just use `{upsert:true}` on `update`. Otherwise you've done it correctly.

Comment: Why not have a unique index on `name`?

Comment: @robertklep, could you explain how a unique index would solve this?

Comment: @MatUtter insert `new_doc`, if name exists already you'll get an uniqueness violation error, if name doesn't exist the document has been inserted and you can retrieve the document from the result.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot a searching I found some [answers in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35626040/findoneandupdate-used-with-returnnewdocumenttrue-returns-the-original-document), but here's a clean example with `findOneAndUpdate` and the `returnOriginal` property set `false`

```
col.findOneAndUpdate(
    query,
    new_doc,
    { upsert: true, returnOriginal:false }
)
.then(update => update.value)
.then(doc => console.log(doc))
```

Comment: Be aware that any properties in `new_doc` will overwrite the properties in the database if the document already exists.