# nodejs mongoDB findOneAndUpdate(); returns true even after database is updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, ionic-framework

i am working on an Ionic-1 + nodejs + angular application. My mongoDb `findOneAndUpdate()` function returns true on each call even the first call updates database.
nodejs:

```
app.post('/booking', function (req, res) {

var collection = req.db.get('restaurant');
var id = req.body.id;
var status = req.body.status;
collection.findOneAndUpdate({status: status, id: id},{$set:{status:"booked"}}, function (e, doc) {
    console.log(id, status);
    if (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
     else if(!doc) {
        res.send(false);
    }
     else {
        res.send(true);
    }
});
});
```

controller.js

```
$scope.bookMe = function(id){
    var Obj = {status: "yes", id: id};
    myService.booking(Obj).success(function(res){
        console.log(Obj, "Checking  status")
        console.log(res);
        if (res == true) {
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Booking Confirm',
            template: 'Thanks For Booking'
            });
    }
    else{
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Error',
            template: ' Not available'
            });
    }
    })

};
```

where i am doing wrong. my DB gets updated but it returns true always on next call.

Comment: What is the output of console.log(id, status), and doc on the second time

Comment: console.log(id, status);
output:
1 yes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get updated document back from the findOneAndUpdate method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35626040/how-to-get-updated-document-back-from-the-findoneandupdate-method)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation about [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) says :

> Finds a matching document, updates it according to the update arg, passing any options, and returns the found document (if any) to the callback. The query executes immediately if callback is passed.

So it's regular behavior you got a `doc`.

Comment: so which function should i use to update and check ?

Comment: I don't get your problem here. If the data do not exist in database, `doc` is false. If the data exists, it `update` it and `doc` equals the data. (if you want the data to get created in case it do not exists, set `upsert` option to true)

Comment: problem is if a user books a restaurant database checks id and status of that restaurant, if status says available, status updates to booked. but in my case if another user book the same restaurant it also showing him booking confirmation even database is updated.

Comment: You should try to `console.log` the `doc` and see what you send back to the user `(res)`. It should work. My guess is when you do `if (res == true)`, res is casted to boolean and tho to `true`, but actually `res.send(false)` is sent

Comment: console.log(doc);
OutPut:
`{ lastErrorObject: { updatedExisting: false, n: 0 },
  value: null,
  ok: 1 } `

Comment: So exactly, you have to interpret the data of doc. Because it will always evaluate to `true`

Comment: how can i interpret `doc` i am novice in JS

Answer (score 0):

#### Note:

1. Since you are checking availability `status="yes"`, Better hard code, instead of getting it from request query/data.
2. Change the response according to your requirement  `res.send(true)/ res.send(false)`.

#### Following code will work

```
app.post('/booking', function (req, res) {

  var collection = req.db.get('restaurant');

  collection.findOneAndUpdate({
        status: "yes",
       _id: req.body.id
     }, {
        $set: {
        status: "booked"
     }
  }, function (err, result) {
   
        //Error handling
        if (err) {
           return res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
        }

       //Send response based on the required
        if (result.hasOwnProperty("value") && 
          result.value !== null) {
             res.send(true);
        } else {
             res.send(false);
        }
   });
});
```