# findOneAndUpdate with async await not returning new document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The below code is updating the database but is not returning the new document despite specifically stating 'returnNewDocument' to be true. I am not using mongoose but instead, I'm am using the MongoDB drivers as found here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
...
const mongo = new MongoClient(process.env.MONGODB_CONNECTION_URI, {
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});
if (mongo) {
  mongo.connect();
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use(cors());
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));
  app.listen(8080, () => console.log("Server running on 8080"));
}

app.get("/v1/editprofile", function(req, res) {
  const { givenName, familyName, mobile, address, serviceRadius, language }  = req.query;
  if (req.cookies && req.cookies.participant) {
    jwt.verify(req.cookies.participant, privateKey, { algorithms: ["RS256"] }, function(err, decoded) {
      if (err) res.status(400).send({ status: "logout", description: "Bad Cookie found" });
      

    async function insertProfile() {
        const id = decoded.id;
        const data = await mongo
        .db("Users")
        .collection("participants")
        .findOneAndUpdate(
          { id },
          {
            $set: {
              givenName, 
              familyName, 
              mobile, 
              address, 
              serviceRadius, 
              language
            }
          },
          { 
            upsert: true, 
            returnNewDocument: true 
          }
        );
        if (data) {
          const participant = data.value
          console.log(participant)
          res.status(200).send({ participant });
        }
      }


      insertProfile().catch(console.error);

    });
  } else {
    res.status(400).send({ status: "logout", description: "No Cookie found" });
  }
});
```

Comment: What library you using for mongo queries? Some libraries may have their own oprtions builder, so they may expect not `returnNewDocument`, but like in mongoose `new`..etc. So check library documentation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [findOneAndUpdate used with returnNewDocument:true returns the Original document MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35626040/findoneandupdate-used-with-returnnewdocumenttrue-returns-the-original-document)

Comment: Unfortunately, it references the node driver, not the MongoDB one as found here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/#behavior

Comment: { 
            new: true
             
          }
remove upsert true and returnNew document just add above line

Comment: I thought `new: true` is a mongoose thing

Comment: @Bill  You are using the node driver, not the mongo shell. Your links point to mongodb shell documentation.

Comment: I have updated my question to show the connection method

Comment: How does the update changes the question? Connection method doesn't matter. It's express app, i.e. nodejs. The only way to query mongodb from nodejs is by using native driver.

Answer (score 0):

By official [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/#behavior) for mongo, you have to provide `returnNewDocument: true` explicitly, because it is returning by default old document, before it was updated.

Same thing if you use [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html), but you just have to provide `new: true` in 3rd object. 1st one is find query, 2nd update query, and 3rd is extra options

Comment: I have indeed set `returnNewDocument: true` but I'm not getting the new document