# Why mongo db response value before update

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to update collection and return updated value. My code is:

```
const someFunction = async () => {
  const { value } = await dataStore.customerSettings.findOneAndUpdate(
            { organizationId }, 
            { $push: { archivedSuppliers: archivedSupplier } }
          );
  return value;
}
```

Problem is that the value is equal to collection object **before** update. Why is it? And how to get updated value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose: findOneAndUpdate doesn't return updated document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811510/mongoose-findoneandupdate-doesnt-return-updated-document) and other similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35626040/findoneandupdate-used-with-returnnewdocumenttrue-returns-the-original-document)

Answer (score 4):

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.0/interfaces/findandmodifyoptions.html#returnoriginal

```
findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, options, callback)
```

pass option

```
returnOriginal: false
```

> When false, returns the updated document rather than the original. The default is true.

---

```
await dataStore.customerSettings.findOneAndUpdate(
            { organizationId }, 
            { $push: { archivedSuppliers: archivedSupplier } },
            { returnOriginal: false } // add here
);
```