# Mongoose remove from collection without model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My MongoDB has a `sessions` collection that is created by a module. The collection has no model or anything since it is not created by Mongoose.

How can I access this collection without specifying it's model?

I tried the following:

```
mongoose.connection.db.sessions.remove({'session.userId': userId}, function(e, found) {
    console.log(found);
    res.json({success: true});
});
```

Although I received the error of: `Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined`

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/10519504/3284355 see the edit of correct answer. You can use mongo native driver package since it's already installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Querying the collection directly will only solve part of your problem.

From the looks of it, you're using `express-session` and `connect-mongo` to manage sessions. This will store the session data (`req.session`) as a JSON *string* in the database:

```
{
  "_id": "fLBj_McMFM-7PwVNsv9ov88vOAgoNiDa",
  "session": "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":null,\"expires\":null,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"userId\":\"my-user-id\"}",
  "expires": ISODate("2016-07-09T08:47:38.156Z")
}
```

As you can see, `session` is a string, not an object, so you can't query it directly using `session.userId`.

If you can't use [`req.session.destroy()`](https://github.com/expressjs/session#sessiondestroy), you need to perform a regular expression query to match against the user id in the JSON string:

```
let collection = mongoose.connection.db.collection('sessions');
let query      = new RegExp(`"userId":"${userId}"`);
collection.remove({ session : query }, function(e, found) {
  console.log(found);
  res.json({success: true});
});
```

It's probably best if `userId` is first run through something like [`escape-string-regexp`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/escape-string-regexp) to make sure that any special characters are escaped properly.

Note that this isn't a fast query, especially if you have a lot of sessions in your database.

**EDIT**: I just found the [`stringify`](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo#more-options) option for `connect-mongo` which, if set to `false`, should write the session data as a regular object to MongoDB, and not as a JSON string.

Comment: You're assumptions are correct. I'm using `express-session` with `connect-mongo` to manage my sessions. On a `POST` to my logout API, I need to destroy these sessions. I have managed to do so by calling `req.session = null` inside my API and setting `unset: 'destroy'` in my session settings. Although, there is one small problem; my home page (`app.get('/',...)`) serves a different page if `req.session.userId` is not undefined. For some reason, I need to refresh my page twice after the logout API is called for it to be unset.

Comment: @Fizzix can you check in the database if the session belonging to the session key has been deleted after the request to the logout route? Or if perhaps `req.session.destroy()` works better?