# Skip timestamps middleware for certain updates in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

My application uses Mongoose and has a schema that uses the [timestamps option](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps):

```
var fooSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
}, {
    timestamps: true,
});
mongoose.model('Foo', fooSchema);
```

So whenever an update is written to the collection, the `updatedAt` property is changed to the current date. But now I would like to add some changes that should *not* update the `updatedAt` property.
Some answers on Stackoverflow ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519432/how-to-do-raw-mongodb-operations-in-mongoose)) suggested to use `Foo.collection` as that allegedly accesses the native MongoDB driver. So I tried this:

```
Foo.collection.update({ _id: someFooId }, { $set: { name: 'New Name' } });
```

However, that changed the `updatedAt` property as well.

So how can I update a document, *without* changing `updatedAt`?

Comment: I have this same exact problem. Did you ever find a solution/workaround for this?

Comment: @danii No unfortunately not. I removed the timestamps middleware and update the timestamps manually where necessary.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From mongoose 5 onwards , there is timestamps option which can be passed in Model.updateOne() and model.update() to skip timestamps for this update.

Directly from [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate):

> [options.timestamps=null] «Boolean» If set to false and schema-level timestamps are enabled, skip timestamps for this update. Note that this allows you to overwrite timestamps. Does nothing if schema-level timestamps are not set.

For example given in the question , timestamp updates can be skipped like this ,

```
Foo.updateOne({ __id: someFooId },{ $set: { name: updatedName } }, { timestamps: false });
```

Comment: "{ timestamps: false }" is working correctly on mongodb v4.2.3. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 12):

I just found a solution and it works perfectly to me.

```
mongoose.connection.db.collection('player').updateOne(
    {_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('56cb91sf34746f14678934ba')},
    {$set: {name: 'Test'}}
);
```

This query will not update the `updatedAt` field. Hope you still need this!

Comment: two years later, face the same issue, google for answers, find old thread w/my comments on it (which I had of course completely forgotten about), get completely valid answer. Gotta love Stackoverflow :) Edit: This answer should be accepted, it's perfect for this usecase. No it's never too late, thanks!!

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution, as you're accessing the driver to bypass the middleware. This will also skip validations and other features. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64634344/1496274 seems to be the solution if you're using Mongoose 5+

Answer (score -1):

What i can get is you are automatically updating the dateTime of `updated_at` field. You must be passing a default value for the `updated_at` in your schema, just remove that default field.

For example.

```
var fooSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
}, {
    updated_at:{
         type: Date,
         default: Date.now
    }
});
mongoose.model('Foo', fooSchema);
```

Remove the `default field` from `updated_at` and your schema will look like this.

```
var fooSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
}, {
    updated_at: Date
});
mongoose.model('Foo', fooSchema);
```

Comment: "You must be passing a default value for the updated_at in your schema" No, the posted schema is the complete one. And the second parameter of `Schema` is for options, there is not `updated_at` option, though.

Comment: then how is your `updatedAt` field is getting updated if there is no such key present? ps. i put `updated_at` in reference to your `updatedAt` only.

Comment: See [timestamp options](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps) as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Ok, instead of using it, you should pass `updatedAt` key directly into your schema as using `timestamps` will auto update everytime you update the document. You can refer the schema i mentioned.

Comment: Yes that is possible of course. But I would like to avoid updating it manually.

Comment: You need not let user pass the value evrytime but whenever you want to update the field, just pass `fooSchema.updatedAt = Date.now` in your routes where you are exporting the schema.

Comment: I do know that. But I still would like to avoid that as it may be forgotten. It should always be updated automatically, except for a small set of queries.

Comment: Downvoted as this answer misses the `timestamp: true` feature and thus is not helpful.