# how to prevent updating of "updatedAt" field while saving or updating documents in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am in a situation where i want to update documents of collection in mongodb but i don't want "updatedAt" field to be updated. I want to retain the previous value of updated field. Please help.

Comment: if no need to update `updatedAt` filed on update  then why need `updatedAt` field ?

Comment: I want to retain the previous value of updated field.

Comment: Mongo does not update the value of any user defined field on its own. If you don't want to update a field simply don't update it.

Comment: I replied in this question [Skip timestamps middleware for certain updates in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38621790/skip-timestamps-middleware-for-certain-updates-in-mongoose/45707811#45707811). Hope this help!

Comment: thanks $set solves this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updatedAt field is updated when you use update query of mongoose. if we directly use [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set) query it will only update the mentioned fields inside $ set query. The reason is updatedAt field is managed by mongoose not by mongodb.

Comment: The $set alone is not sufficient on mongodb version 4.2.3. { timestamps: false } should be used with the $set. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64634344/6003002

Answer (score 2):

If you are using mongoose, then relatively new feature (2020) gives you the option to override setting timestamps (or just one) on transactions.

[Refer to docs](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/timestamps)

Example from docs shown below

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  email: String
}, { timestamps: true });

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

const doc = await User.findOneAndUpdate({email: 'test@google.com'}, {email:'newtest@google.com'}, 
{new:true, upsert: true, timestamps:false});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Waterline or other database abstractions, my advice is to run the query natively in mongo.

This is how I would fix this in Sails.js (running Waterline):

```js
let someQuery = {name: 'John Doe'}; 

MyModel.native(function (err, collection){
  collection.update(
    {query: someQuery},                   // Which documents to update?
    {$set:{field1: "value", foo:"bar"}},  // Our new values
    {multi: true},                        // To support update of multiple fields
    function(err, result){
      if (err) console.log(err)
      else console.log(result.result)
    })
});
```